# OpenACC support in GCC

Tags: gcc, openacc

Using this [tutorial](http://scelementary.com/2015/04/25/openacc-in-gcc.html) I tried to install GCC with OpenACC support but unfortunately when I tried execute 'make' after this command:

```
$GCC5ROOT/source/gcc/configure \
--prefix= \
--target=nvptx-none \
--enable-as-accelerator-for="$target" \
--enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto \
--enable-checking=yes,df,fold,rtl \
--disable-multilib \
--with-sysroot=/nvptx-none \
--with-build-sysroot=$GCC5ROOT/install/nvptx-none \
--with-build-time-tools=$GCC5ROOT/install/nvptx-none/bin \
--disable-sjlj-exceptions \
--enable-newlib-io-long-long \
CC='gcc -m64'\
CXX='g++ -m64'
```

the following error occurs:

> checking for suffix of object files... configure: error: in
>   `/home/nikos/Desktop/openacc/build/gcc5-accel/nvptx-none/libgcc':
>   configure: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot
>   compile

Comment: Can you use the script here https://github.com/olcf/OLCFHack15/tree/master/GCC5OffloadTest to install it and see how it turns out. The script basically combines all steps that you had to manually do. Maybe there's some environment variable that you missed.